# How to run chkdsk on Windows Server backup drive

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012

I am using Windows Server backup, to backup my files to a USB connected drive. The drive is having issues and I would like to run `chkdsk` on it to see if that fixes it; however, `chkdsk` requires a drive letter and this drive does not have one.

How can I check this drive for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Windows Server backup to backup onto a USB connected drive, Windows will "claim" the drive and it will no longer appear in Windows Explorer or have a Drive Letter. This is fine when the backup is working well, but if you run into problems and need to check the disk for errors, you need a way to identify it.

`VolumnName`

You can find the `VolumnName` by opening an elevated command prompt and entering: `mountvol`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>mountvol
Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point.

MOUNTVOL [drive:]path VolumeName
MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /D
MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /L
MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /P
MOUNTVOL /R
MOUNTVOL /N
MOUNTVOL /E

    path        Specifies the existing NTFS directory where the mount
                point will reside.
    VolumeName  Specifies the volume name that is the target of the mount
                point.
    /D          Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory.
    /L          Lists the mounted volume name for the specified directory.
    /P          Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory,
                dismounts the volume, and makes the volume not mountable.
                You can make the volume mountable again by creating a volume
                mount point.
    /R          Removes volume mount point directories and registry settings
                for volumes that are no longer in the system.
    /N          Disables automatic mounting of new volumes.
    /E          Re-enables automatic mounting of new volumes.

Possible values for VolumeName along with current mount points are:

    \\?\Volume{50ccdaa8-3de1-11e3-93e8-806e6f6e6963}\
        *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

    \\?\Volume{5b7a78f7-d4c8-4a4a-9852-42583cfd70a2}\
        L:\

    \\?\Volume{31d79a25-dc92-4d7c-bb81-8d635a7a2681}\
        D:\

    \\?\Volume{bd293852-3b82-428b-aa50-081f26aad78c}\
        *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

    \\?\Volume{649ccea1-4f8d-11e7-93fe-c81f66ced748}\
        S:\

    \\?\Volume{50ccdaa9-3de1-11e3-93e8-806e6f6e6963}\
        C:\

    \\?\Volume{50ccdab3-3de1-11e3-93e8-806e6f6e6963}\
        H:\


C:\Windows\system32>
```

This will print out a list of possible values that can be used in place of a drive letter. The drive we are looking for us accompanied by the label `*** NO MOUNT POINTS ***`. I then had the problem of not knowing which drive with that label was the backup drive, and which one was the recovery partition.

Another way to determine the `VolumnName` of the drive is to open `Computer Management -> Disk Management`, right click on the drive and open the property window. Once there, go to the security tab and along the top will be a line `Object name` containing the `VolumnName`
[image: ObjectName]

Once the `VolumnName` has been determined, the disk  can be checked by entering 
 `chkdsk /f \\?\Volume{bd293852-3b82-428b-aa50-081f26aad78c}` at the command line.